# What am i doing wrong while trying to use this oracle package/procedure?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, associative-array

I have written this package

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE CURVES AS 
  type t_forecast_values is table of test.column2%TYPE index by varchar(20);
  assoc_array t_forecast_values;
  procedure sp_insert (param1 in varchar2, param2 in number);
END CURVES;

create or replace
package body curves as
  procedure sp_insert (param1 in varchar2, param2 in number) as
  begin
    assoc_array(param1) := param2;
    DECLARE primarykey NUMBER(10);
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1..2
      LOOP
        SELECT seq_curves.nextval INTO primarykey FROM dual;
        INSERT INTO TEST (column1, column2, column3)
        VALUES (primarykey, param1, assoc_array(param1));

        INSERT INTO TEST2 (column1, column2)
        VALUES (primarykey, 'default');
      END LOOP ;
    END;
  end sp_insert;
end curves;
```

I call the procdedure through this c# code:

```
class Program
    {
        private static string connString = @"User Id=User; Password=root; Data Source=SOURCE";

        private static List<string> forecast_types = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
        private static List<double> forecast_values = new List<double> { .1, .2 };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var con = new OracleConnection(connString))
            {
                string query = "BEGIN curves.sp_insert(:forecast_types, :forecast_values); END;";

                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = query;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.BindByName = true;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
                            {
                                ParameterName = ":forecast_types",
                                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                                Value = forecast_types.ToArray(),
                                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                                CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
                            }
                        );
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = ":forecast_values",
                            OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Double,
                            Value = forecast_values.ToArray(),
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                            CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
                        }
                        );

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

i get the following error:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: 
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_INSERT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_INSERT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored at     Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at OracleTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in \\comp\user$\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\OracleTest\OracleTest\Program.cs:line 57
```

I have no idea to resolve the problem, yet. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your package is not accepting a PLSQL Associative array, but rather single elements.  What you are trying to do, I believe, is do an array insert (which is pretty much packaging up in C# your code X times and bulk sending it to the database to do the work)

this link directly describes what you want to do:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/windows/odpnet/howto/arraybind/index.html

(I made a few changes to your code, namely

1. removed the pl/sql assoc. array para type
2. added ArrayBindCount
3. You were using an anonymous block, changed this to a stored procedure call

1 & 2 should fix your problem, while #3 is more of syntactic sugar

however, this code is untested but out to work

```
class Program
    {
        private static string connString = @"User Id=User; Password=root; Data Source=SOURCE";

        private static List<string> forecast_types = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
        private static List<double> forecast_values = new List<double> { .1, .2 };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var con = new OracleConnection(connString))
            {
                //string query = "BEGIN curves.sp_insert(:forecast_types, :forecast_values); END;";
                string query = "curves.sp_insert";

                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = query;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; // CommandType.Text; //you can change this to a stored procedure and not utilize the anonymous block

                        cmd.ArrayBindCount = 2; //use ArrayBindCount

                        cmd.BindByName = true;

                     cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = ":forecast_types",
                            OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                            Value = forecast_types.ToArray(),
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                            //CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray //this is not needed
                        }
                    );
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = ":forecast_values",
                        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Double,
                        Value = forecast_values.ToArray(),
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                        //CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray  //this is not needed
                    }
                        );

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**EDIT**

---

I did notice that you did *try* to pass in an associative array (I see the creation of the type of the looping within the procedure).

This is not too difficult to do either.
On that note you are on the correct track.

you'll need to change the package to have assoc. arrays passed in via params
    CREATE OR REPLACE 
    PACKAGE CURVES AS 
      type t_forecast_values is table of test.column2%TYPE index by varchar(20);
      assoc_array t_forecast_values;

```
  --need to create an assoc.array for numbers
  type t_numbera_values is table of test.column2%TYPE index by number(10);

  --changed to accept the assoc.array to varchar and numbers
  procedure sp_insert (param1 in t_forecast_values, param2 in t_numbera_values);
END CURVES;

create or replace
PACKAGE BODY CURVES AS
  --changed to accept the assoc.array to varchar and numbers
  PROCEDURE SP_INSERT (PARAM1 IN T_FORECAST_VALUES, PARAM2 IN T_NUMBERA_VALUES) AS
  BEGIN
    --assoc_array(param1) := param2; /*not sure what the intent of this was...*/
    DECLARE PRIMARYKEY NUMBER(10);
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN PARAM1.first .. PARAM1.last
      LOOP
        SELECT seq_curves.nextval INTO primarykey FROM dual;
        INSERT INTO TEST (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
        VALUES (primarykey, PARAM1(i), PARAM2(i));

        INSERT INTO TEST2 (column1, column2)
        VALUES (PRIMARYKEY, 'default');
      END LOOP ;
      --assuming you are going to add error handling here
    END;
  end sp_insert;
END CURVES;
```

and you will need to add a size param to the param list as such

```
class Program
    {
        private static string connString = @"User Id=User; Password=root; Data Source=SOURCE";

        private static List<string> forecast_types = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
        private static List<double> forecast_values = new List<double> { .1, .2 };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var con = new OracleConnection(connString))
            {
                string query = "curves.sp_insert";

                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = query;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.BindByName = true;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
                            {
                                ParameterName = "param1",
                                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                                Value = forecast_types.ToArray(),
                                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                                CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
                                Size = 2
                            }
                        );
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = "param2",
                            OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Double,
                            Value = forecast_values.ToArray(),
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                            CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
                            Size = 2                            
                        }
                        );

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

to get a great example of this goto 
ORACLE_HOME\odp.net\samples\2.x\AssocArray\AssocArray.cs
it does exactly what you like

all of the above code is untested but should get you on the correct track, either from array binding (first example) or passing in the pl/sql array (second example)

Comment: I am using.net Version 3.5 for my application, param1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;. This line showing the error. What namespace need to use ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but I believe the `OracleDbType.Double` would map to the database type `FLOAT`, not `NUMBER` which is the declared type of the second parameter.  I think you should be setting the type of the second parameter to `OracleDbType.Decimal` per [this table](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm).

Comment: In Oracle, `FLOAT` is a synonym of `NUMBER` and can be used interchangeably. `FLOAT` is really just provided for ANSI compliance.  Which is all a roundabout way of saying that I don't think this is the source of the problem.

Comment: @Allan, you're right.  I was thinking of `BINARY_FLOAT` which is a distinct datatype.  I don't generally use anything but NUMBER so forgot the distinction.  Thanks.